# Javascript populate Telerik MVC combobox from an array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, combobox, telerik-mvc

my application is MVC4; I am trying to populate a Telerik MVC using json, the result is an array; however I get only one item; here is my script:

```
  function CheckWord() {
        var wordtocheck = $('#Cword').val();
        alert(wordtocheck);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/CheckWord',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                cword: wordtocheck
            },
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.array.length; ++i) {
                    var myString = data.array[i];
                    var mySplitResult = myString.split("-->");
                    var hms = mySplitResult[0];
                    var a1 = hms.split(',');
                    var a2 = a1[0];
                    var a = a2.split(':');
                    var start = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);
                    var hms1 = mySplitResult[1];
                    var b1 = hms1.split(',');
                    var b2 = b1[0];
                    var b = b2.split(':');
                    var end = (+b[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+b[1]) * 60 + (+b[2]);
                    var dropDownList = $('#ComboBox').data('tComboBox');
                     dropDownList.dataBind([
                     { Text: start[i] + "-" + end[i], Value: start[i] + "-" + end[i] }]);
                     dropDownList.select(0);
                }
            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });
```

When I add [i] after start and end, I get undefined!  without [i] I get the correct value however just one item.  Would appreciate your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Comment: post /Home/CheckWord controller code

Comment: also try [i] , then step through with a breakpoint , it may be working just fine for a few items in the array until it hits that undefined part , look at actual response in browser traffic , and use debugger to see where the error is being thrown

Comment: I checked with breakpoint (debugger;) I get the values of start and end, however they are list contains one line only; it does not append!    Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem:

```
  function CheckWord() {
        var wordtocheck = $('#Cword').val();
        alert(wordtocheck);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/CheckWord',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                cword: wordtocheck
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var listData = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.array.length; ++i) {
                    var myString = data.array[i];
                    var mySplitResult = myString.split("-->");
                    var hms = mySplitResult[0];
                    var a1 = hms.split(',');
                    var a2 = a1[0];
                    var a = a2.split(':');
                    var start = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);
                    var hms1 = mySplitResult[1];
                    var b1 = hms1.split(',');
                    var b2 = b1[0];
                    var b = b2.split(':');
                    var end = (+b[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+b[1]) * 60 + (+b[2]);
                    listData[i] = { Text: myString, Value: start };

                }
                var dropDownList = $('#ComboBox').data('tComboBox');
                // debugger;
                dropDownList.dataBind(listData);
                dropDownList.select(0);
            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });
    }
```

Hope this will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following link will help

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/mvc/radcombobox-populate-on-client-side.aspx

Here you can see

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="radProject" runat="server" Skin="Default" Width="300px" 
EnableLoadOnDemand="true" Filter="Contains" OnClientItemsRequesting="getProjects" 
EmptyMessage="Select Project" />
```

in the above code EnableLoadOnDemand is set to true and Filter is set to contains and the event bound to OnClientItemsRequesting.

```
function getProjects(sender, args) { 
            itemsRequesting(sender, args); 

            $.getJSON( 
            '<%= Url.Action("GetProjects", "Capital") %>', 
            { facility: GetFacility().get_value() }, 
            function(data) { 
                fillCombo(sender, data); 
                sender.highlightAllMatches(sender.get_text()); 
            }); 
        }
```

the above javascript method is executing a ajax call using get JSON with parameters and the sub methods fillCombo is filling the combo box.

// Use this for all of your RadComboBox to populate from JQuery

```
 function fillCombo(combo, result) { 
            combo.clearItems(); 

            var items = result.d || result; 

            // This just lets your users know that nothing was returned with their search 
            if (items.length == 0) { 
                var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem(); 
                comboItem.set_text("Nothing found"); 
                comboItem.set_value("null"); 
                combo.get_items().add(comboItem); 
                combo.set_text(""); 
            } 

            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
                var item = items[i]; 

                var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem(); 
                comboItem.set_text(item.Text); 
                comboItem.set_value(item.Value); 
                combo.get_items().add(comboItem); 
            } 
        }
```

Now in order to cancel the default behavious of RADComboBox you can use the following code

// This cancels the default RadComboBox behavior

```
function itemsRequesting(sender, args) { 
            if (args.set_cancel != null) { 
                args.set_cancel(true); 
            } 
            if (sender.get_emptyMessage() == sender.get_text()) 
                sender.set_text(""); 
        }
```

I hope the above solution will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks, but I am using Telerik MVC combobox not RadComboBox.